# Included PDF gets corrupted after Acrobat’s color conversion

Tags: color, pdf, pdfpages, acrobat

I found a strange error … I’m typesetting a musical score with Sibelius 7. And to add some text and notes I use LaTeX (i.e. `xelatex` but the error is the same with `pdflatex`). To get a complete PDF of the text and the score I use `pdfpages` to input the score PDF into the TeX document, like this

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\includepdf{score}
\end{document}
```

Which produces this output:

[image: Input to Acrobat]

To change the color of some other included images I use Acrobat’s color conversion (Gray Gamma 1.8; keep black) and that make the result look bad:

[image: Acrobat’s output]

**Proceeding**
Create `score.pdf` with Sibelius 7
→ include `score.pdf` in `input.tex` with `pdfpages`
→ run `pdflatex input` or `xelatex input`
→ open `input.pdf` with Acrobat [first screenshot]
→ convert colors using “Gray Gamma 1.8” and “keep black“ (?) option
→ save converted PDF as `output.pdf` [second screenshot]

If I color convert `score.pdf` directly with Arcobat there are no problems, why I guess there is an issue with `pdfpages` … any ideas?

You can find all files in [this ZIP (http://tweh.de/texsx/pdfpages_error.zip)](http://tweh.de/texsx/pdfpages_error.zip) (its my server).

---

I asked the same question in the german typography community [typografie.info (direct link to my question)](http://www.typografie.info/3/topic/28266-acrobat-pdf-in-pdf-wir-komisch-nach-farbumwandlung/).

---

Since I didn’t find a real solution yet I started a third thread at [HilfDirSelbst.ch](http://www.hilfdirselbst.ch/gforum/gforum.cgi?post=511200#511200) (in german). It seems like it’s an Acrobat bug but I’m not sure right now. I’ll be back here if it comes out as a TeX problem … ;-)

Comment: That ensemble bracket hints that there are some pen options passed prematurely or illegally since the line width has changed.

Comment: @percusse: Thanks. Can you say at which point the error occurs, i.e. which author should get a bug report?

Comment: I wish I knew. To be honest, it's just a hunch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some time elapse and I did some research in other communities – this is the sad result:

- The line width error is a (now reported) bug in Acrobat
- The cropped font is a Sibelius bug (now reported too)

The only thing I can do is to wait for the fixes and find a clever workaround in the meantime …